# Comparing Zscore per values and mark them as NaN if it goes above a certain score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to work on a requirement where I am computing the Zscore and want to compare with individual values in the rows. If Zscore>1 mark them as `NaN` for those specific values. I am marking it as `NaN`, so that I could fill those values by appropriate techniques.

I have the below code:

```
s={'2014':[1,1,2,2],'2015':[12,22,33,44],'2016':[55,66,77,88],'2017':[2,3,4,5]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)

     2014 2015 2016 2017
   0    1   12  55   2
   1    1   22  66   3
   2    2   33  77   4
   3    2   44  88   5
```

I have computed zscore as -

```
df_zscore = (p - p.mean())/p.std()

       2014       2015        2016       2017
0   -0.866025   -1.139879   -1.161895   -1.161895
1   -0.866025   -0.416146   -0.387298   -0.387298
2   0.866025    0.379960    0.387298    0.387298
3   0.866025    1.176065    1.161895    1.161895
```

If Zscore>1, then the desired output should be like:

```
       2014       2015        2016       2017
0      1          12          55         2
1      1          22          66         3
2      2          33          77         4
3      2          NaN         NaN       NaN
```

(They are marked as NaN, since Zscore was >1)

How would I be able to get here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `mask` it:

```
df_zscore = (p - p.mean()) / p.std()
out = p.mask(df_zscore > 1)
```

Output:

```
   2014  2015  2016  2017
0     1  12.0  55.0   2.0
1     1  22.0  66.0   3.0
2     2  33.0  77.0   4.0
3     2   NaN   NaN   NaN
```